# Set plot dimension in ggsave

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggsave in order to export my plots and save them in png images... I am using, banally

```
ggsave(G, filename="TEST6.png", scale=2, width=5, height=2, dpi=300, units=c("cm"))
```

the problem is, I have multiple graph to save and they all have the same x axis, but different scale for the y axis... which means that the dimension of the plots are slightly different (for example, one of the scales only goes from 0 to 3, but another one goes from 0 to 150 which means that if I set the same dimensions, the plot is "squished" in the second graph). 
Is there a way to specify the dimension of the x axis in ggsave?

Comment: When you save multiple plots, what exactly does the code look like? Do you use this same code line for all plots? I guess not, since they would be overridden with the same filename. If you write a separate code line to save every one of your plots then I do not see the problem in giving each of them a different heigth.

Comment: I just change the name and save them as different files, I don't need them to be a single file, just to be the same size so that they don't look weird when I put in in my paper

Comment: If the graphs need to be a specific size, then your only option is to play with parameters of the actual plot in ggplot. Maybe have a look at scale_y_continuous() function or coord_cartesian() function.